# Estimates for functions with polynomial growth

Tags: analysis, functions

Suppose function $g(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following polynomial growth condition:
$$|g(x)^{(j)}| \leq K(1 + |x|^{p-j}), \quad j = 0,1,2,3$$
for some constants $K>0, p\geq 3$, where the superscript $(j)$ denotes the $j$-th order derivative.
Now define the following function on $\mathbb{R}$
$$h(x) = g(x) - g^{(2)}(x)\cdot x^2,$$
how can I rigorously show that
$$|h(x) - h(y)| \leq K(1 + |x|^{p-1} + |y|^{p-1})|x-y|.$$

I know the Taylor expansion should apply, but there would be some lower order term which I do not know how to control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use $h'\left( x \right) = g'\left( x \right)-2xg''(x) - g'''( x )x^2$ and the Newton-Leibniz rule.